# asp.net gridview RowDataBound method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowdatabound

There's a way to build a link button with CommandName directive within the GridView RowDataBound method?
I can only create html elements such as: link, img, or simply text.
thanks a lot.

PS. I prefer vb.net code instead of c#!!

Comment: Don't use `DataBound` or `RowDataBound` since these events are triggered only if the `GridView` is databound. But you need to recreate dynamical controls on every postback. So use `RowCreated` to create dynamical controls and use `RowDataBound` to databound them(you can access them there since they are already created at this stage).

Comment: I was sleeping.... Is enough to retrieve the link button created in design mode with "findControl" directive and you can personalize any things! Better late that never! :D
Thanks Tim for your contribute